# smack 4.2 incoming messages

Tags: android, listener, message, smack

I can send masseges now and my next step is to receive the incoming messages. i was searching for much methods . Most of them are depracted or not available in my version of smack. im using smack 4.2.0. maybe someone could tell me how and where i could implement a listener who catches all incoming messages ? 
here my code:

MainActivity.class

package com.example.saddam.xmpp3;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;

import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    TextView chat;
    final  connectXmpp con = new connectXmpp();

    public MainActivity() throws XmppStringprepException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        con.execute();

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        chat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AbstractXMPPConnection conn=con.getConnection();
                con.sendMessage(conn,chat);


            }
        });


    }
    }
```

connectXmpp.class

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jxmpp.jid.EntityBareJid;
import org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate;
import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;


import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * Created by saddam on 08.07.2017.
 */

public class connectXmpp extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    static AbstractXMPPConnection conn2= null;


    final EntityBareJid jid   = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("hss404@im.koderoot.net");

    public connectXmpp() throws XmppStringprepException {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = null;
        try {
            config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password")
                    .setXmppDomain("dismail.de")
                    .setHost("dismail.de")
                    .setPort(5222).setKeystoreType(null)
                    .build();
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

        try {
            conn2.connect();
            conn2.login();


        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }




        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    public AbstractXMPPConnection getConnection(){
        return conn2;
    }

    public ChatManager getChatMana(AbstractXMPPConnection c){
       ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(c);
        return chatManager;
    }

    public void sendMessage(final AbstractXMPPConnection c, TextView t){
        ChatManager chatManager = null;

        Message newMessage = null;
        chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(c);

        try {


            Chat chat = chatManager.chatWith(jid);
            newMessage = new Message();
            newMessage.setBody(t.getText().toString());
            chat.send(newMessage);


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Smack 4.2 you can use the following interface: **IncomingChatMessageListener**.

Sample code:

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
chatManager.addIncomingListener(new IncomingChatMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void newIncomingMessage(EntityBareJid from, Message message, Chat chat) {
                // Your code to handle the incoming message
            }
        });
```

You also have to add the following statement to your **XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration:**

```
.setSendPresence(true)
```

If the presence is false or not set, then all your incoming messages will be saved in your Offline message storage and the interface will not be triggered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its working fine for one-to-one chat.. but not working for group chat. Is there any other code for group incoming messages ?

Comment: Of course, for this case you can use the MutliUserChat. Here are the docs: https://docs.jivesoftware.com/smack/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html

Answer (score 0):

The way you can listen for incoming messages is like this:

```
    //Declare your stanza listener
    private MessagePacketListener messagePacketListener;

    //In your cotnructor   
    messagePacketListener = new MessagePacketListener(context);

    //Then in your login method register your stanza listener like this
    public void login() throws SmackInvocationException, XmppStringprepException {
        connect();

        try {
            if (!con.isAuthenticated()) {
                setupOmemo(con);
                ....
                con.addSyncStanzaListener(messagePacketListener, new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class));
                ....
                initOmemo();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ....
        }
    }

    //Now you have your MessagePacketListener that process the incoming messages
    public class MessagePacketListener implements StanzaListener{
    private Context context;

    MessagePacketListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
        Message msg = (Message)packet;

        //Message that have body
        if(msg.getBodies().size() > 0){
            //Text message
            //Do something with message msg.getBody()
        }
        else{
            //This must be sth like delivery receipt or Chat state msg
        }
    }
}
```